# How do I go about troubleshooting this ANT aapt error (null returns 255)

Tags: android, ant, aapt

I am fairly new to ant and Team City, but have had a few builds up and running for the last few months, however one just started to fail yesterday, and I have spent the greater part of the intervening hours totally failing to understand it.

The application is an Java Android app built in Eclipse (that builds fine) then uploaded to svn, monitored by Team City.

The relevant section of my build log is as follows.

```
[09:15:13][Step 4/5] -code-gen (1s)
[09:15:13][-code-gen] mergemanifest
[09:15:13][-code-gen] do-only-if-manifest-hasCode (1s)
[do-only-if-manifest-hasCode] sequential (1s)
[09:15:13][sequential] if (1s)
[09:15:13][if] echo
[09:15:13]Handling aidl files...
[09:15:13][if] aidl
[09:15:13]No AIDL files to compile.
[09:15:13][if] echo
[09:15:13]----------
[09:15:13][if] echo
[09:15:13]Handling RenderScript files...
[09:15:13][if] echo
[09:15:13]----------
[09:15:13][if] echo
[09:15:13]Handling Resources...
[09:15:13][if] aapt (1s)
[09:15:13][aapt] Generating resource IDs...
[09:15:14][aapt] null returned: 255 
[do-only-if-manifest-hasCode] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 255
```

The build step previously to this does an `ant clean`, which appears to be the generic fix all answer for these sort of questions.

This check in did add a new string value and ui item reference, however nothing out of the ordinary, and the code has checked in correctly.

The very few references I can find referring to error 255 is a generic 'something bad happened' error.

Can anyone provide some pointers as to how I can troubleshoot (or preferably fix) this particular build error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much work, most of it around `proguard.txt`, which is what line 698 refers to, I realised that this was a red herring. `Proguard.txt` was simply the last parameter that `aapt` was being passed, and it was `aapt` that was having the issue.

Checking the lines above the error, I discovered what I was looking for.

As it happened, my `strings.xml` file had corrupted whilst checking in (I'm not sure how that happened), and that was causing the build to fail the `[aapt] Generating resource IDs...` step.

I rechecked in the `string.xml` and the build ran fine.